# Write to the first cell of a range

Tags: excel, range, vba

I have a set of ranges and I want to write a value in the first cell of each range:

```
Range("AccessabilityRange").Item(1, 1).Value = "Accessibility"
```

I have tried a few variations but none of them are working. Do I need to extract the cell address first and then write to that? I have also seen offset used and count but not sure why one would be chosen over another?

Comment: The error I get is: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Comment: Does it matter if there is already text in the cell perhaps?

Comment: So try to specify Sheets("sheetName").Range(.... something like this one Sheets("Sheet3").Range("mainRange").Item(1, 1).Value = "val". It doesnt matter is there is already text, but probably you dont have specified sheet, and you focusing sheet without your named range

Comment: Thank you - now I get a different error: Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: The check your range name, as Tom mentioned bellow. Your name AccessabilityRange is really correct? or it should be AccessibilityRange? And can you update your code in question?

Comment: pls try this in immediate window `?ActiveWorkbook.Names("AccessabilityRange").RefersTo` and tell us what is returned

Comment: What do you mean by the immediate window?

Answer (score 1):

You need to address the cells in the range

```
Range("AccessabilityRange").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Accessibility"
```

Comment: from my try, it works same as .Item, so he probably have another issue

Comment: Well then it is probably to do with the declaration of the `Range`. Can you check that the range is indeed that and it can find it on the sheet. Accessibility is spelt with an `i` so I'd check your spelling of the range and failing that call it out with the sheet as well so `Sheet1.Range("AccessabilityRange").Cells(1,1).Value`

Comment: Fortunately I have spelt Accessibility consistently wrong throughout the code so that isn't the problem! Thank you - I cannot work out what the problem is. Is there a way I could get a message box to say what cells are in the range to check if that is not correct?

Comment: You could use `Range("AccessabilityRange").Address` to get the address it points at and `Range("AccessabilityRange").Parent.Name` to see the name of the sheet it is looking at

Comment: @PaulBarr you can check named range in excel under formulas tab and name manager